# how to wrap gorilla mux func handler by yaag middleware

Tags: go, gorilla

I am following this tutorial. http://thenewstack.io/make-a-restful-json-api-go/

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
for _, route := range routes {
    router.
        Methods(route.Method).
        Path(route.Pattern).
        Name(route.Name).
        Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
}
```

I need to wrap the endpoint func using yaag middleware.

```
r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.HandleFunc(handler))
```

How to achieve this?

EDIT:
I am wrapping in around the Logger and returning the haddler. Logger takes first argument, as http.Handle. So wrapping the route.HandlerFunc won't work. Can you please help me here?

```
handler := Logger(route.HandlerFunc, route.Name)

    router.
        Methods(route.Method).
        Path(route.Pattern).
        Name(route.Name).
        Handler(handler)
```

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is substitute .Handler() by **.HandlerFunc()** and wrap your handler function with the middleware, so each endpoint will pass first for the yaag middleware and then to your handler function, like this:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
for _, route := range routes {
    router.
        Methods(route.Method).
        Path(route.Pattern).
        Name(route.Name).
        HandlerFunc(middleware.HandleFunc(route.HandlerFunc)) // change here
}
```